# What is the Zeta function $Z(q,T)$ for $q=7$ for the curve $y^2=x^3+x+1$?

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves, zeta-functions

I am reading Joe Silverman's book The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, pg. 140, and I am trying to compute $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the complex numbers which help to evaluate the zeta function for the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+x+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_7$. The shape should be

$$Z(V / \mathbb{F}_q;T) = \exp(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\#V(F_{q^n})\frac{T^n}{n})$$
$$=\frac{(1-\alpha T)(1-\beta T)}{(1-T)(1-qT)}$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The fact that the polynomials appearing the numerator and denominator are quadratic in $T$ has to do with the fact that elliptic curves are one dimensional objects (over $\mathbb{C}$, so have to do with dimensions of Weil cohomology groups).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The curve has 5 points defined over $\mathbb F_7$,
$$ E(\mathbb F_7) = \lbrace(0,1),(0,6),(2,2),(2,5),\infty\rbrace, $$
so
$$ a_7 = 7+1-5 = 3. $$
Hence the numerator of the zeta function is
$$ 1 - a_pT + pT^2 = 1 - 3T + 7T^2. $$
The roots are
$$ \alpha=\frac{3+\sqrt{19}i}{14}\quad\text{and}\quad
\beta=\frac{3-\sqrt{19}i}{14}.$$

Comment: Thank you, Joe. I really appreciate your help. The Git repo has been updated and you are acknowledged: https://github.com/jacksonwalters/elliptic-curves-finite-fields.